# Which executable is called if called within script via relative path?

Tags: scripting

Say I have this script `mm` in `dir1`:

```
#Contents of mm
echo "Hello Main!"
./hd
```

My pwd is `dir2`, and I now execute `mm`:

```
$ ../dir1/mm
```

There is an executable named `hd` in both `dir1` and `dir2`. I tried it and the `hd` in `dir2` is executed. Why isn't `hd` in `dir1` executed instead?

Comment: Is `dir2` in your `$PATH`?

Comment: No, it's not there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because execing a file doesn't change the current working directory of your process into the directory of the file.

The executable may choose do it after it's exec'ed. E.g., I sometimes do:

```
cd "$(dirname "$0")"
```

in my script to make sure my current working directory is the directory of the executable, but it's under no obligation to do so.